# O que é granularidade de serviços?

Tags: web-service, soa

O que é granularidade de serviços em SOA?

Qual a diferença entre granularidade fina e grossa?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta foi sucinta e precisa, e não há qualquer problema com ela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "granularidade de serviços" é utilizada para mensurar a profundidade de abstração 
que foi aplicado nos serviços.

A granularidade pode ser dividida em duas partes, sendo:

- Granularidade fina (fine-grained):
  Determina que precisamos de muitos "grãos".
  Teremos serviços com poucas operações, mas dividiremos essas operações por vários serviços.

Exemplo: Dividir operações de um CRUD de clientes via serviço WCF em dois serviços

**ServicoCadastroCliente** com operações/métodos CriarCliente(), AtualizarCliente() e ExcluirCliente()

**ServicoValidarCadastroCliente** com operações/métodos ValidarCliente(), ValidarAtualizacaoCliente() e ValidarExclusaoCliente

- Granularidade grossa (coarse-grained):
  Determina que teremos poucos "grãos", bem maiores.
  Teremos poucos serviços, mas cada um deles conterá uma porção bem maior de operações.

Exemplo: Definir apenas um serviço para as operações de um CRUD de clientes via serviço WCF

**ServicoCadastroCliente** com operações/métodos CriarCliente(), AtualizarCliente(), ExcluirCliente(), ValidarCliente(), ValidarAtualizacaoCliente() e ValidarExclusaoCliente